# Flask: Querying inherited classes from SQLAlchemy brings different results in two similar contexts

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on a project with two different users: client, employee. Clients post and Employees confirm the posts or not. To do this I have on User class which deals mostly with authentication and basic procedures, and both the Client and Employee class inherit from it.
Practically:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    user_type = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': user_type}

class Client(User):
    __tablename__ = 'client'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'client'}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    telephone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    birthday = db.Column(db.String(120))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

class Employee(User):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'employee'}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    employee_extra = db.Column(db.String(140))
```

---

When I want to get all the clients in one of my routes which is something like:

```
@bp.route('/posts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def posts():
    clients = Client.query.all()
    print(clients[0].birthday)
```

I get results like: `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'birthday'.` because the result is `[<User 2>]`.

---

On the other hand, when I set up an environment for testing, and I run the same query.

```
    db_app.setUp()
    #    self.app = create_app(Config)
    #    self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
    #    self.app_context.push()
    #    db.create_all()
    #    self.client = self.app.test_client()
    #    db.session.commit()
    
    db_app.create_user('11123123123','user@gmail.com','123123123','client')
    print(Client.query.all())
```

It brings the necessary results: `[<Client 2>]`

I have read on different sources, and main documentation of SQLAlchemy, but cant really see where this difference comes from. What am I missing?

Comment: That makes no sense `clients = Client.query.all()` this code prints the list of the `Users` table? Try to print `clients`.

Comment: I did, and it prints: `[<User 2>]` .

Comment: Is this the only user you have committed to the db? perhaps you can try to use a new db

Comment: Sorry, I moved forward with my coding and striped the information from the Client and Employee, and appended them to the User (just like using on single user with Nullable properties for now). I have to reach a deadline, and I will come back after Monday for this. I will bring a running example after reducing my code.